# How to Integrate Login with Amazon with Pay with Amazon API v2?

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-pay, login-with-amazon

In my website I have implemented [Login with Amazon Button](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/javascript-sdk-reference.html) to login into website and [Pay with Amazon API v2](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-recurring-checkout/get-set-up-for-integration.html) for recurring payment of subscription.

After login, When I proceed with "Pay with Amazon" button. I have to login again even after using "Login with Amazon" button. is there any way to skip this step as both services are from Amazon? cant i continue with same account info i got using Login with amazon button?

Comment: Clicking the Pay button always results in being redirected to Amazon for choosing the payment method and address (and if necessary sign in before being able to do so).
If it is the same browser session as the Login, the sign in step should be skipped.
However, there is no way to "hand over" the login data on your side. This is for security reasons all handled by Amazon.
In fact, Login and Pay are completely separate features and Login is only designed to help you provide an alternative sign in method for your app and not for starting a Pay session.

Comment: I am in same browsing session, still I have to login once using pay with amazon button. Afterwards I do not need to login again to use Pay with amazon till browser session expires. @marcus.kreusch

Comment: It might be, that Amazon separates those logins on their side. In any case, you cannot influence this behavior. Depending on the customer journey, you want to build, I'd recommend using the Pay button over the Login button wherever possible (e.g. a login form that is displayed when the shopper starts the checkout: use the Pay button instead of Login)

Comment: hey my website have many other functionalities except purchase. Login Authentication is required for me. lets see what can i do @marcus.kreusch